# insert into table foo from select query from table bar

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I had two MySQL tables, `foo` and `bar`. Table `foo` is like this:

```
mysql> desc foo;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| biz  | varchar(255)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| buzz | mediumtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

table `bar` is like this:

```
mysql> desc bar;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| quux          | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| blah          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now suppose I wanted all of `bar.quux` to be inserted into `foo.biz` and all of `bar.blah` to be inserted into `foo.buzz`.  Why can't I do something like this:

```
insert into foo (biz, buzz) values (select quux as biz, blah as buzz from bar);
```

Is there a way to DWIM without recourse to a script?

Comment: You mean `INSERT INTO foo(biz, buzz) SELECT quux, blah FROM bar;`?

Answer (score 1):

The way to DWIM is to [read the documentation for INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/insert.html).

If you use the `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (...)` form, then you specify one or more row constructors in parentheses.

If you use the `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...`, then you don't use the `VALUES` clause. The rows come from the `SELECT` statement.

In your case, don't use `VALUES` or parentheses.

```
insert into foo (biz, buzz) 
select quux as biz, blah as buzz from bar;
```

P.S.: It does no harm to assign column aliases in your `SELECT` query, but it's not necessary. The column names in the select-list are ignored.

Comment: Seems like the parentheses were holding me back...